# Problem using a proxy with Java under Lotus Notes

Tags: java, proxy, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I've been searching the whole web for a problem that I have with a lotus notes agent. Here is my resquest.
I need to retreive a Webservice (in Java) from an agent in Java too. The problem is that the agent must run on the server because the Jar file cannot be installed on every computer. Now, on the client's network, people must go thru a Proxy to access the web, which needs an authentication. I know that we can set the Domino server to use a proxy, but it's already set to LDAP. So, the only option I found is to use Java system properties to connect to the proxy and then get the webservice. So, I set http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort and I use the Authenticator for the login and password. When I connected via HTTP to retreive the webservice, everything is fine, or seems fine, since I get a valid Java object. Now once I get that instance, I need to initialize a session. When I launch the method, I get this:

```
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error: WebServiceEngineFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out: connect:could be due to invalid address
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out: connect:could be due to invalid address
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at com.casebank.spotlight.webservice.TroubleShootSoap11BindingStub.initiateSession(TroubleShootSoap11BindingStub.java:334)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at JProxyManager.getResultFromAddress(JProxyManager.java:118)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.JavaConnectInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
2011-06-28 13:46:50   Agent  error:     at lotus.domino.JavaConnectLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

That tells me that Java is trying to connect using Sockets, which aren't HTTP protocol. So, I tryied setting the socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort to the same Proxy using the port 1080 instead of HTTP 8080, but I keep getting the same error. My searches made me realize that maybe Java doesn't use the SOCKS proxy at all, even if those properties are set. What I don't get, is that I can do it with the HTTP proxy (didn't work at first, but after setting the properties, it had) but not the SOCKS Proxy. It just doesn't want. One interesting thing that might help me but I couldn't find anything about that, is that at first, I didn't have the proxy address, so I typed a dummy one just to start doing the code while the client was answering my email. When I clear the properties socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort, the exception I get from Java is UnknowHostException which points to my dummy address. NOWHERE (and I searched!) is written that address anymore. Even when I print the properties usign this:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

I don't see it. I don't think that the client might have set the dummy proxy address exactly like I did and since it's running on server, it has nothing to do with my config. The Java version on notes is 1.4 and the class java.net.Proxy is not on the server. I was just wondering it brings somthing to your mind. I even tryied setting all possible properties that are related to Proxies (http, https, ftp, socks) and I'm getting crazy! There must be a way and I feel I'm close, but I'm realy tired of testing bunch of things that doesn't work!

You help is realy appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Java uses sockets to talk to the http proxy.  It would make perfect sense though if this was trying to reach the server directly instead of going through the http proxy.

I would suggest you locate the jar containing this code, and run it through a decompiler to see what the code actually does and where this exception was triggerede.  It looks like it does not wrap the actual exception but creates a new one discarding the actual stack trace.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping! I had already decompiled the jar and located the exception, but decompliers don't do a clean job. It's using an object of the type **lotus.domino.axis.client.Call** and launch the method _invoke_ which return an Object that might be the expected value or an exception. If the exception is RemoteException, it throws it back (which I catch). Otherwise, it returns me the expected value. But you are right, it doesn't want to go in the proxy. It's two lines, one after the other. First one works, the other doesn't!!!

Comment: I rechecked in the decompiled files, and it has never went thru the proxy! So it just doesn't work...

Comment: the proxy stuff happens in the runtime library not in the client.  but when you know which call it makes you can configure accordingly or perhaps even provide replacement classes doing what ou want.